# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emailAddress' of undefined" VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm having trouble figuring this out with the vuex store. I have a created a subscription form to be able to enter your email address and I want to make a post request to the backend api but the data is not showing when I console.log it. It only console.logs the item that has been dispatch to the store and when I'm trying to mutate the item to the state.emailAddress and try to get the data that to the POST I get an empty object. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OdWp.jpg)

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pizzaItems: [],
    shopCart: [],
    choosePizzaSize: [],
    total: 0,
    deliveryCharge: 0,
    emailAddress: '',
  },
  getters: {
    deliveryCharge: state => state.deliveryCharge,
    pizzaItems: state => state.pizzaItems,
    shopCart: state => state.shopCart,
    choosePizzaSize: state => state.choosePizzaSize,
    checkOut: state => state.total,
  },
  mutations: {
    Add_To_Cart(state, item) {
      const shopItem = state.shopCart.find(x => x.id === item.id && x.size === item.size);
      if (shopItem) {
        shopItem.count += item.count;
      } else {
        state.shopCart.push(item);
      }
    },
    Price_Total(state, total) {
      state.total = total;
    },
    fetchProducts(state, products) {
      state.pizzaItems = products;
    },
    fetchPizzasize(state, size) {
      state.choosePizzaSize = size;
    },
    free_Shipping(state, freeshipping) {
      state.deliveryCharge = freeshipping;
    },
    subScribeMail(state, item) {
      state.emailAddress = item;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    fetchData({ commit }) {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/saltbageproducts').then((response) => {
        commit('fetchProducts', response.data.products);
        commit('fetchPizzasize', response.data.pizzasize[0].pizzaSize);
      })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
    addTocart(context, item) {
      context.commit('Add_To_Cart', item);
    },
    priceCalculation(context, item) {
      context.commit('Price_Total', item);
    },
    changeFreeshippingStatus(context, shipping) {
      context.commit('free_Shipping', shipping);
    },
    emailCheckUp(context, item, state) {
      context.commit('subScribeMail', item);
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/saltbagehome', {
        email: state.emailAddress,
      }).then((reponse) => {
        console.log(reponse.data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    },
  },
  modules: {
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoording [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions);

> Register actions on the store. The handler function receives a context
>   object that exposes the following properties:
>
> ```
> {
>   state,      // same as `store.state`, or local state if in modules
>   rootState,  // same as `store.state`, only in modules
>   commit,     // same as `store.commit`
>   dispatch,   // same as `store.dispatch`
>   getters,    // same as `store.getters`, or local getters if in modules
>   rootGetters // same as `store.getters`, only in modules
> }
> ```
>
> And also receives a second payload argument if there is one.

Then in your first parameter of your action u have the vuex context, there should be:

```
emailCheckUp(context, item) { ... }
```

instead of

```
emailCheckUp(context, item, state) { ... }
```

now to access to vuex context inside of your action, just:

```
emailCheckUp(context, item) {
  context.commit('subScribeMail', item);
  ...
  email: context.state.emailAddress,
  ...
}
```

In practice, they often use ES2015 argument [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify the code a bit:

```
emailCheckUp({commit, state}, item) {
  commit('subScribeMail', item);
  ...
  email: state.emailAddress,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian Carrillo